# Give tzedakah/maaser ksafim in property (not cash)

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

Usually I think of giving maaser ksafim as donating money. Does it also count to give (movable) property?

For example, if someone with a $100k income wants to give 20%, is it ok to donate a car worth $20k instead of handing over a check for $20k?